# Simplifying the sum of a fraction and an integer under a radical sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to help my little bro, a bit rusty here... [Wolfram Alpha is telling me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+x%281%2B%28+%28x%5E2%29+%2F+%2816-%28x%5E2%29%29+%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29) that:

$$
x\sqrt{1+{\frac{x^2}{16-x^2}}}
$$

simplifies to:

$$
4x\sqrt{\frac1{16-x^2}}
$$

I can't for the life of me figure out why.  I'm thinking there's a simple rule I'm forgetting about..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the common denominator within the radical sign. $$x\sqrt {1 + \frac {x^2}{16 - x^2}} = x\sqrt {\frac {(16 - x^2) + x^2}{16 - x^2}} = x\sqrt{\frac{16}{16- x^2}}=4x \sqrt{\frac{1}{16 - x^2}}$$

In the last step, we simplify $\sqrt{16} = 4$.

Comment: there it is... i tried 100 things.  can you make inline equations in comments?  i didn't see the $-x^2$ and $x^2$ cancel out.  i was blind, and now i see, ty

Comment: You're welcome! We all overlook simple things, sometimes!

Answer (score 4):

$x\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}}{16-x^{2}}}=x\sqrt{\frac{16-x^{2}}{16-x^{2}}+\frac{x^{2}}{16-x^{2}}}=x\sqrt{\frac{16-x^2+x^2}{16-x^2}}=x\sqrt{\frac{16}{16-x^2}}=4x\sqrt{\frac{1}{16-x^2}}$

Comment: ok, amWhy beat me.

Comment: yea, but i gave you (+1) 10 points anyway.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Think back to adding fractions. Also, remember how to move factors in and out of a square root.